# StackOverflow loads very slow

Tags: support, stack-exchange

StackOverflow and meta loads quiet slow for me (Germany). Is there some maintance?

E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/full.en.js?v=07def1e83957 loaded on this ask question page 18.35 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Loads almost instantly for me (434ms) in the UK. There were no recent deployments either.

Comment: I experience  similar issues. Now and then I'm greeted with 408 Request Time-out

Comment: I added a screenshot on reload.

Comment: Are you having such slowdowns with other sites? Just wondering if this is an ISP issue on your end.

Comment: Nope other sites work fine. Even if they are hosted in the US.

Comment: I see a timeout in the tracert from above.net to pnap.net

Comment: It seems intermittent though

Comment: Now it loads fast again for me...

Comment: It looks like it drops packets between `ae3.er4.lga5.us.above.net [64.125.31.246]` and  `border1.po1-20g-bbnet1.nym008.pnap.net [216.52.95.1]`. I'm still seeing this.

Comment: Now I have again problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Via the [@StackStatus](http://twitter.com/StackStatus) twitter account:

> Our data center neighbors are being hit with a DDoS attack, we are being affected intermittently as well.  Stop attacking people ya jerks.

I have a feeling you're catching the effects of that.